# python defaultdict and increment/aggregate a value

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to create a dictionary in which i have to keep incrementing a value

So i am trying the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
test = defaultdict(dict)
for item in debitlist:
    if not something:
        test[item['name']]['count'] += 1
        test[item['name']]['amount'] += item['name']['amount']
```

I am trying to get a dictionary like

```
{ "Krishna" : { "count" : totalcount, "amount" : totalamount } }
```

I am getting Keyerror for count. How to resolve this and get what i want

Comment: You need the internal dictionary to also be a `defaultdict` but with a default of `int` or `float`.

Comment: Ok. how to achieve this if defaultdict is not possible

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the internal dictionary to also be a `defaultdict` but with a default of `int` or `float`.

Make a function to create a `defaultdict` with a number as default, e.g:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def floatdict():
    return defaultdict(float)
```

Then you can use it in place of the vanilla `dict` you were previously using:

```
test = defaultdict(floatdict)
```

Then:

```
test['Krishna']['count'] += 1
test['Krishna']['amount'] += 10
```

You can convert the `defaultdict` back to a `dict` and `print` it:

```
print(dict(test['Krishna']))
```

Output:

```
{'amount': 10.0, 'count': 1.0}
```

Comment: what is the need of function. cant we define test = defaultdict(float)

Comment: I tried and says `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: `test` would be a dictionary of `float` values. You want a dictionary of dictionaries of float values.

Comment: It looks like you haven't done exactly what I suggested. Are you sure you're using it `defaultdict(floatdict)`?

Comment: Can i have mixed items i.e count as int, amount as float, branch as str

Comment: No. You could use dict.setdefault instead. That would allow you to set defaults per key. Read the docs and search for questions about it if you need to understand further. Would link for you to save your effort but am on mobile so difficult.